# Type: Error Message: Call to a member function driver() on null Filename: /home/kedr7614/public_html/system/libraries/Cart.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

please help meeee

i have error like this
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function driver() on null

Filename: /home/kedr7614/public_html/system/libraries/Cart.php

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that you're trying to call a method on an non-existing variable or the variable containing your object has a null value in Cart.php file.

The following code will returns you the same error :

```
$my_object = null;
$my_object->driver()
```

You have to create an instance of your class to have access to drive method like so :

```
class MyClass {
    public function driver() {
         return 1;
    }
}

$my_object = new MyClass();
$my_object->driver();
```

Comment: where do i make this code ?
class MyClass {
    public function driver() {
         return 1;
    }
}

$my_object = new MyClass();
$my_object->driver();

Comment: It's just for example, the problem come from /libraries/Cart.php. Look for any call of  ->driver() methods and you will find where is the problem. I can't help you more than that without the source code